# Using t-sql to select a dataset with duplicate values removed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of tables in SQL Server 2005 which contain timeseries data. There is hence a datetime field and a set of values.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[raw_data](
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [field1] [float] NULL,
    [field2] [float] NULL,
    [field3] [float] NULL
)
```

The datetime field is unfortunately not a unique key, and there appear to be a lot of datetime values with multiple (non-identical) entries - hence DISTINCT doesn't work.

I want to select data from these tables for insertion into a new, properly indexed table.

Hence I want a select query that will return a dataset with a single row entry for each Time. I am not concerned which set of values is selected for a given time, as long as one (and only one) is chosen.

There are a LOT of these tables, so I do not have time to find and manually purge duplicate values, so a standard HAVING COUNT(*)>1 query is not applicable. There are also too many duplicates to just ignore those time values altogether.

Any ideas? I was thinking of some kind of cursor based on PARTITION BY, but got stuck beyond that point.

Comment: If you want a basis t-sql you could use:

select T.*

from dbo.rawdata as T, (select time, min(filed1) as C from 
dbo.rawdata group by time) as Ta
where t.time = ta.time
and t.field1 = ta.field1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a cursor:

```
SELECT tmp.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Time] ORDER BY [Time]) AS RowNum
    FROM raw_data
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Yup, that's the kind of approach I'd take.

Comment: Doesn't that just ignore the duplicate time values altogether, or am I misunderstanding PARTITION?

Comment: @meepmeep: It'll return a single row for each distinct `Time` value: `PARTITION BY` creates a "window" for each distinct `Time` value; `ROW_NUMBER` gives each row within each partition an ascending number from 1 to *N*; the outer query just returns all rows where the row number is *1* (that is, the first row from each partition).

Comment: Aha! I was misunderstanding PARTITION, that's far more useful than I ever realised. Thank you!